# Why isn't my button disabled using ng-disabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I work with angular and try to disable a button if a value from my scope is 'true'. I saw the `ng-disabled` which seems to be perfect but I don't know why it doesn't work...

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <h4>{{ building.isBuildable }}</h4>
        <button ng-click='build(building.id)' 
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                ng-disabled="!build.isBuildable">
       Build
       </button>
</div>
```

And my angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('Colony', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        isBuildable: function () {
            return true;
            //return false;
        }
    };
});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Colony', function ($scope, Colony) {
    'use strict';
     var building = {
         name: 'Building Name',
         isBuildable: null
     };
     $scope.building = building;
     $scope.building.isBuildable = Colony.isBuildable();   
     $scope.build = function (id) {

     };
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xz7arL0s/1/

As you can see in the jsfiddle, it's always disabled even when `isBuildable` is true. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo, you're referring to **build** instead of **building** in the `ng-disabled` binding.

Update your code to:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <h4>{{ building.isBuildable }}</h4>
        <button ng-click='build(building.id)' 
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                ng-disabled="!building.isBuildable">
       Build
       </button>
</div>
```

I edited this also on the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz7arL0s/2/).